# How to create multiple rows in excel based on a particular field

Tags: excel, office365

I would like to create 4 additional rows based on data in column(4) . Can you help me with a script?

Below is my data
[Source excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS9om.png)

End result should look like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8TVJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

In VBA code you can call [`.Insert` on a Range object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.insert).

It is well documented so you should be able to figure out the correct syntax for your case.

Here's some tutorials for an example:

- [Inserting Rows in Excel Worksheet using VBA](https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/insert-rows-worksheet/)
- [Excel VBA Insert Row: Step-by-Step Guide and 9 Code Examples to Insert Rows with Macros](https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-insert-row/)